# Converting csv row into csv columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hello I am trying to make one csv from another csv file.

Below is my input file in csv.

```
1  2
3  4
5  6
```

And my desired output like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Basically I am trying to convert each row into column.

```
csvfile = open('main.csv', 'r')
textcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')


for row in textcsv:
    list_ = list(row)
    column = pd.DataFrame(list_)
    outputDF = pd.concat([outputDF, column], axis=1)
outputDF.to_csv(output.csv, sep=',',  index=False)
```

I got the output which convert row in column but not repeated.

Comment: You desired input and output look equals. Are you trying to transpose the dataframe? Or do you want a single column as output?

Comment: @Valentino its not same. It's kind of multiple column. Each row value will be new column.

Comment: I edited the display to properly show the array layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [`pd.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df)
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.stack())
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df2)
```

[image]

```
df2.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',',  index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want multiple type of output. Like each row convert into column.

Comment: @ShamjibhaiSolanki Updated with `.stack`

Comment: Voyla its something helpful. Thanks buddy.